# Can't update version code in Android Studio for mac from build.gradle

Tags: android, version-control, build.gradle

I currently have build version 1 and the Google Play store wants me to update the build version before releasing the app.

In Gradle Scripts > build.gradle(Module:app) the versionCode is 1.

If I change it to 1.1 (say), the program wants to sync.

But when I sync, the build fails immediately with the starting message of:

"Could not find method versionCode() for arguments [1.1] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultA..." etc

If I go to Project Structure > Flavors , it's already updated to 1.1 so I don't see what else I need to change.

The version number in the manifest is not the version code in build.gradle, because by default it's 1.0, which corresponds to the default version number 1.0 (not version code 1) in build.gradle.

Any ideas?

I have also tried making the change direct from Project structure but result was the same.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version code is a Integer it should 1,2,3... so on
It will used by play store to update the APK

Version code always be incremental. Increment the version code in each release.

Version Name which is visual display where you can put like "1.0-Beta", "1.0.1" etc.

For more details checkout the below link

[Android Version](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)